# Replicating WPF TabControl selected TabItem design time behavior for a custom control

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls, tabcontrol, selecteditem

I'm developing a custom control which shows an inline popup window and I would like to use a similar technique as the TabControl employes so that only popup windows that are selected within the designer or more commonly by placing the cursor within the popup declaration in XAML that it is visualized right within the desiger without having to run the application or change any runtime values by hand.

I've started by duplicating the implementation of the TabControl which I have successfully mimicking everything but it is all copied from Reflector output and Stylesnooper. I've renamed all of the control parts and then replaced the default templates so that the main control uses an ItemsPresenter instead of a ContentPresenter to show the individual popup controls within a Grid panel overlayed on top of one another. So far this is working great too. The problem is that somewhere along the line I lost the ability to have the designer follow the item that is selected in the XAML editor.

Either an explanation of how the TabControl's design time behavior functionality actually works to describe the selected TabItem behavior that I described above or just some pointers on how one could achieve what I'm tryign to do would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To solve a similar problem, I had to create design time support for my custom tab control.  Here is a link for [WPF Designer Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Basically, I created a PrimarySelectionAdornerProvider to handle click interaction and a FeatureConnector<> / FeatureProvider pair for selection changes (including selection changes made in the xaml editor).

The feature provider / connector:

```
[FeatureConnector(typeof(AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureConnector))]
class AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureProvider : FeatureProvider
{
    public AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureProvider()
        : base()
    {
        // sole purpose is to register the connector
    }

}
class AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureConnector : FeatureConnector<AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureProvider>
{
    public AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureConnector(FeatureManager manager)
        : base(manager)
    {
        SelectionOperations.Subscribe(this.Context, SelectionChanged);
    }

    private void SelectionChanged(Selection selection)
    {
        if (selection.PrimarySelection != null)
        {
            // navigate tree to find parent (custom tab page and custom tab control)
            for (ModelItem item = selection.PrimarySelection; item != null; item = item.Parent)
            {
                // once found, select appropriate tab
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit (more info):

This [Microsoft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675304%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) has a number of links to walk-throughs that should help.  Here are the basic steps to get started:

1. Create a new project, MyAssembly.VisualStudio.Design.dll.
2. The library should compile to the same location as MyAssembly.dll (important).
3. Add references to Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility and Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.
4. Add a reference to your control library.
5. Create a class called [Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee849819%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Code:

```
internal class Metadata : IProvideAttributeTable
{
    // Accessed by the designer to register any design-time metadata.
    public AttributeTable AttributeTable
    {
        get
        {
            AttributeTableBuilder builder = new AttributeTableBuilder();

            // Add the adorner provider to the design-time metadata.
            builder.AddCustomAttributes(
                typeof(MyControl), // rename to your control's name
                new FeatureAttribute(typeof(MyPrimaryAdornerProvider)), // rename to whatever you will call your PrimaryAdornerProvider
                new FeatureAttribute(typeof(AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureProvider)) // rename to whatever you will call your SelectionFeatureProvider
                );

            return builder.CreateTable();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Create a class MyPrimaryAdornerProvider from [PrimarySelectionAdornerProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907306%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (rename to whatever you want).  See link for good walk-through.
2. Create the AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureProvider and AutoTabPageSelectionFeatureConnector from the example above.

Comment: Had a chance to come back to your post and try out your suggestion. Unfortunately I have about 0 experience working with writing designers and/or WPF automation so it's a bit over my head. Do I have to place this type of code inside of a MyAssembly.Designer.dll assembly within a magic "Design" folder? Could you elaborate on the rest of the steps needed to get this hooked up. Otherwise do you have a reference to a tutorial that could bring me up to speed on just the necessary parts to get this hooked up for my custom control?